# Trying to convert a string to integer causes a error of type System.FormatException

Tags: c#, enums, converters, formatexception

I am making a client for my server and I am stuck. My server is sending Unicode text, and my client recieves it. The problem is this piece of code:

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(FTPCommands), Convert.ToInt32(replace[0].Trim()))
```

I am trying to get the text from my Enum `FTPCommands` with the number the server sent me. First my client is recieving the ID: `1 732847823`(Result from the debugger).

It splits correctly, in this case: 
`replace[0].ToString()` -->"1"
 AND `replace[1].ToString()` -->"732847823"

No error occurs!

On the second command, the client is recieving an error from the server:

`8 Server is too full, try again laiter`

And it also splits correctly, in this case:

`replace[0].ToString()` -->"1"
  AND  `replace[0].ToString()` -->"8"
  AND  `replace[1].ToString()` -->"Server"
  AND  `replace[2].ToString()` -->"is"
  AND  `replace[3].ToString()` -->"too"
  AND  `replace[4].ToString()` -->"full,"
  AND  `replace[4].ToString()` -->"try"
  AND  `replace[4].ToString()` -->"again"
  AND  `replace[4].ToString()` -->"laiter"

And now the error occurs!
I dont know why this is working with the first command and not also with the command `8`.
If I replace the `replace[0].Trim()` with the number 8 it works fine.
What is wrong with the code, or what could cause that error? Is it because I am using Unicode?

*Here are some samples of my code:*

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                //SendFileToServer(@"\\fs1\home\manuel.boehmler\contacts.rar", client);
                AnswerToServer(FTPCommands.ID,null,sw);
                AnswerToServer(FTPCommands.Username, txtBUserName.Text, sw);
                AnswerToServer(FTPCommands.Password, txtBPassword.Text, sw);
                AnswerToServer(FTPCommands.login,null, sw);
                AnswerToServer(FTPCommands.MaxMbytes, txtBPassword.Text, sw);

                //AnswerToServer(FTPCommands.FileTransfer,"", sw);


                string line = null;
                while (client.Connected == true)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = sr.ReadLine()) && line.Length >= 2)
                    {

                        RichTxtMessage("Bekommt: " + line, true);
                        string[] replace = null;
                        string command = "";

    replace = line.Split(' ');
    command = replace[0].ToUpperInvariant();

    string arguments = replace.Length > 1 ? line.Substring(replace[0].Length + 1) : null;

    switch (Enum.GetName(typeof(FTPCommands), Convert.ToInt32(replace[0].Trim())).ToUpperInvariant()) //Error occurs here
    {
        case "ID":
          RichTxtMessage(arguments,true);
          break;
        case "ERROR":
          RichTxtMessage(arguments, true);
          break;
    }
}

public enum FTPCommands
{

    Persmission = 0,
    ID = 1,
    Username = 2,
    Password = 3,
    UserNameReq = 4,
    PasswordReq = 5,

    Chat = 6,
    MessageRecived = 7,
    Error = 8,
    Warning = 9
}
```

**EDIT (UPDATE):**

When Iam using UTF8 as encoding the console gives me this result back:
[image: CMD, streamwriter with UTF8]

As you can see the wired symbols as first char. However it doesnt show me the symboles when Iam using UNICODE (but still not working). I solved the problem, I dont use any Encoding for my FTP-Server

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the line and checking the value is what you think it is (or write it to the console if you can't use the debugger)?

Comment: It is unlikely to be a Unicode issue, since the digits 0 to 9 are in the ASCII range 0 to 127, and should be represnted in a string with no conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Convert.ToInt32(replace[0].Trim()))
use int.TryParse:

```
int i = 0;
int.TryParse(replace[0].Trim(), out i)
```

Edit: If null was in an element, that element cannot be converted as int and it will throw error

```
string arguments = replace.Length > 1 ? line.Substring(replace[0].Length + 1) : null;

switch (Enum.GetName(typeof(FTPCommands), Convert.ToInt32(replace[0].Trim())).ToUpperInvariant()) //Error occurs here
```

Assign some int instead of null, or check it is not null or empty before converting to int

```
  string arguments = replace.Length > 1 ? line.Substring(replace[0].Length + 1) : "-1";

// OR do this
int opt = 0;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(replace[0].Trim())
opt = int.TryParse(replace[0].Trim(), out opt);
switch (Enum.GetName(typeof(FTPCommands), Convert.ToInt32(opt)).ToUpperInvariant())       //Error occurs here
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I dont know why Convert.ToInt32() didnt worked.

Comment: Ok nvm. It is not working also. I dont know whats wrong with Conversion from string to int.

Comment: Please confirm that your replace[0] produces a valid string to convert as int. Make sure there are no white spaces added. As you mentioned if it is working when you use trim, it has whitespace with the string and it cant be converted as int. So use trim() before converting the string to int. Make sure that the the string is 1 (one), Not l(alphabet L)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are bothering to convert the integer to a string. You could just cast to the enum and use switch with just enum values, e.g.

```
int id = -1;
if (int.TryParse (replace[0].Trim (), id))
{
    switch ((FTPCommands)id)
    {
        case FTPCommands.ID:
            RichTxtMessage(arguments,true);
            break;
        case FTPCommands.Error:   
            RichTxtMessage(arguments, true);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thats true, but when Iam doing this i have to lockup what the number is

Comment: I don't understand. The string has been converted to a number. I am saving you from having to convert the integer to a string, and then compare it against another string. In any case, the code as you provided would be comparing "Error" with "ERROR".

Comment: Iam sorry I forgote to add `.ToUpperInvariant()`. Just gave you a upvote because your solution also would be correct.

Comment: You should edit `if (int.TryParse(replace[0].Trim(),id))` to       `if (int.TryParse(replace[0].Trim(),out id))`

Comment: It is still not fixed. Somehow i cant convert string "1" to 1